# Derivative of $e^{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I used an online derivative calculator to check my answer to this problem, I'm not sure what I did wrong.

To me it seems like $e^{x+1} + 1 = (x+1)e^x$

The online calculator gives $e^{x+1}$ as the derivative. What is the correct answer and why?

Thanks.

Comment: $f(x)=e^{x+1}=e \times e^x\implies f'(x)=e\times e^x=e^{x+1}=f(x)$.

Comment: How did you get your answer? Did you try to apply the chain rule? You might get better answers if you show your process so we can point out where things go wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the rule for differentiation of a *polynomial* being $\frac{d}{dx}x^n = n\cdot x^{n-1}$.  That rule **only works for polynomial terms** and does *not* work where the exponent is $x$ as opposed to the base.

Comment: You are confusing the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ with the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.   Use the chain rule.  $f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$.  $f(x) = e^x$ so $f'(x) = e^x$.  $g(x) = x+1$ so $g'(x) = 1$ so $f'(g(x))g'(x) = e^{x+1}*1 = e^{x+1}$.

Comment: ... or use lulu's slick argument.  That is REALLY slick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is:

$$e^{x+1}$$

We use the chain rule which says:

$$(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

If we let, $f(x)=e^{x}$ and $g(x)=x+1$ then we have $f(g(x))=e^{x+1}$. Now using the chain rule and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ we have:

$$(e^{x+1})'=e^{x+1}(x+1)'$$

But $(x+1)'=1$ so we have:

$$(e^{x+1})'=e^{x+1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand.

Comment: You're welcome ${}{}{}{}{}$ @vivi-d

Comment: @vivi-d Your confusion arises from muddling up polynomials of the form $x^n$ which have derivative of $nx^{n-1}$ with exponentials such as $a^x$ which have derivative of $a^x\cdot\ln a$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^x\right] = e^x,$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp(x)\right] = \exp(x).$$  Then by the chain rule, with the choice $f(x) = \exp(x)$ and $g(x) = x+1$, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(g(x))\right] = f'(g(x)) g'(x) = \frac{df}{dg} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx} = \exp(x+1) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[x+1] = \exp(x+1),$$ and for a general differentiable function $g$, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp(g(x))\right] = \exp(g(x)) g'(x) = g'(x) e^{g(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$f(x) = e^{g(x)}$$

the derivative is

$$f'(x) = g'(x)e^{g(x)}$$

by the Chain Rule of differentiation, provided $g(x)$ is differentiable.

In your case, if we let $g(x) = x+1$ then $g'(x) = 1$, leaving $f(x) = e^{x+1}$ unchanged by differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = e^{x+1}$ and let $u = x+1$. Then we can write, $y = e^u$. By the chain rule,

$$f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{du}(e^u)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(x+1) = e^u\cdot (1) = e^u = e^{x+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice $e^{x+1}=(e)e^x$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e)e^x=e\frac{d}{dx}e^x=(e)e^x=e^{x+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note: $\frac {dx^n}{dx}= nx^{n-1}$. $x$ is the variable in the base, and $n$ is a constant in the exponent.

But $\frac{de^x}{dx} \ne xe^{x-1}$.  $x$ is a variable the exponent, while $e$ is a constant in the base.

You derive based on "what the variable $x$ is doing".  When $x$ is in the exponent it is a very different thing than when $x$ is in the base.

$\frac{de^x}{dx} = e^x$.

Taking a *cute* hint from lulu:

$\frac{de^{x+1}}{dx} = \frac{d(e*e^x)}{dx} = e\frac{d(e^x)}{dx} = e*e^x = e^{x+1}$.

===

Note: $\frac{d(x^n)}{dx} = \lim \frac{(x + h)^n - x^n}{h} = \lim \frac{x^n + n*x^{n-1}*h + a*x^{n-2}h^2 + ..... + h^n - x^n}{h} = \lim \frac {n*x^{n-1}*h + h^2(ax^{n-2} + ...... + h^{n-2})}{h} = \lim n*x^{n-1} + h*(ax^{n-2} +.....) = nx^{n-1}$.

An *entirely* different reason for $e^x$

$\frac{d(e^x)}{dx} = \lim \frac{e^{x+h} - e^x}{h} = \lim \frac{e^xe^h - e^x}{h} = \lim\frac{e^x(e^h - 1)}{h} = e^x * \lim \frac{e^h -1}{h} = e^x * 1$.

Completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [logarithmic differentiation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LogDiff.aspx)

First set your function in terms of $x$ and $y$:

$y=e^{x+1}$

Then take the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) of both sides.

i.e

$ln(y)=ln(e^{x+1})$

$ln(y)= x+1$

Then use [implicit differentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/implicit-differentiation-intro-calc/v/implicit-differentiation-1) to derive both sides of the equation

$1\over{y}$$dy\over{dx}$$=1$

Move $y$ over to the right side by multiplying both sides by $y$.

So:

$dy \over{dx}$$=y$

Which means:

$dy \over{dx}$$=e^{x+1}$

The derivative of $e^{x+1}$ is itself.

Hope this can be helpful.